# Logs not appear

Tags: crash, dmesg, logs

My server today crash and I need know the reason. 
I look inside dmsg log and verify that has a period of time that I do not have log.

Why is is happened?

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMQRC.png)

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text into your question.  You've also not told us what release of Ubuntu you are using, or why you are focusing on `dmesg` (kernel ring buffer) rather than systemd journal/logs.  If it was a hardware error you check your hardware logs (which can vary on make/model..) but is likely off-topic here.  Your question is unclear or too broad.

Comment: Assuming you are usuing a recent version of Ubuntu, `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the last of the previous reboot's logs.